# Wifi keeps dropping connection in my asus laptop

Tags: networking, kernel

Wi-Fi connection drops frequently, unable to reconnect without restarting the system.
This issue has been occurring for a few days but has become more frequent today. It happens at random intervals, even though power management is turned off. Restarting the system is the only way to reconnect to Wi-Fi.

**mainline version** 6.2.0-35-generic

```bash
*-network 
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 31
                serial: 20:4e:f6:58:2c:d5
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=6.2.0-35-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.29.7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.